# Holdout on a collection not working

Tags: render-layers

I am trying to isolate my foreground collection through my scene, I've clicked to holdout the collection and I see it's working in the viewport but when I render it's still there without the holdout.

In the object properties, there's a *Holdout* button, it works when I click it, but I have to individually click it on 1000 objects.

Isn't there another way?

[image: Hold out objects]

[image: My foreground - Studio lights and my Bg - house]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing).

Answer (score 0):

I only had to click this and it worked!
[image: SOLUTION]